# Table Cell Alignment Issue in Outlook when using VML

Tags: html, email, outlook

Seems like I'm having an alignment issue in Outlook 2010 and 2013 when I use vml for a table cell. The multi-colored background image appears fine in the right side table cell. The problem is with the table button(LEARN MORE) in the right side table cell. Instead of being aligned in the middle of the cell,  it aligns to the top of the cell. This only occurs in Outlook 2010 and 2013. I included a jpg and code snippet below. Anybody else come across this?

When I remove the vml code, the button aligns in the middle, Seems like it has something to do with the vml code.

Thank you for your time and guidance.

George

URL to image: http://epidm.edgesuite.net/CMS/BB/Untitled-1.jpg

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td width="420" align="center" valign="middle"><a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="url" width="420" height="71" alt="Left Image" title="Left Image" border="0" style="display:block;"/></a></td>
<td width="180" height="71" align="center" valign="middle" background="http://epidm.edgesuite.net/CMS/BB/bb_w41_dinner_v1_06b.jpg">
    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
    <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:180px;height:71px;">
    <v:fill type="tile" src="http://epidm.edgesuite.net/CMS/BB/bb_w41_dinner_v1_06b.jpg" color="#9db9922" />
    <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
    <![endif]-->
            <table width="122" height="40" align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="middle" style="padding:10px 10px 10px 10px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; color:#ffffff; background-color:#eb298c;"><a href="#" target="_blank" style="color:#fffffe; text-decoration:none; font-weight:bold;">LEARN MORE</a></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
    </v:textbox>
    </v:rect>
    <![endif]-->
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -2):

George,

In case if you didn't know, Outlook uses Word as an email editor. You can read about supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties in the following articles in MSDN:

- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 1 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201%28v=office.12%29.aspx)
- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 2 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338200(v=office.12).aspx)